# How to integrate React Navigation Back Button with a WebView

Tags: reactjs, react-native-webview

I tried following this tutorial https://www.reactnativeschool.com/integrating-react-navigation-back-button-with-a-webview.

Here is my Index.js/App.js code. Any guidance mainly HOW TO ADD adding natigationOptions to Stack.Screen.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import {
  createStackNavigator,
  HeaderBackButton, // new import
} from "@react-navigation/stack";
import Home from "./screens/Home";
import Details from "./screens/Details";
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome";

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: true,
        }}
      >
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Tabs} />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Details"
          component={Details}
          options={({ navigation }) => ({
            headerTitle: "Details",
            headerLeft: (props) => {
              const headerLeftInfo = navigation.getParam("headerLeftInfo");

              if (headerLeftInfo) {
                return (
                  <HeaderBackButton
                    {...props}
                    title={headerLeftInfo.title}
                    onPress={headerLeftInfo.onPress}
                  />
                );
              }
              return <HeaderBackButton {...props} />;
            },
          })}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```

How to add navigationOptions like the code below:

```
const App = createStackNavigator({
  Index: {
    screen: Index,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerTitle: 'Index',
    },
  },
  Details: {
    screen: Details,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      headerTitle: 'Details',
    }),
  },
});
```

Comment: please explain more about the problem and your expectation.

Comment: Currently my code does not work, I think the problem is to do with the navigationOptions